# Shared element transition on back to RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager isn't correct

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

I have problem when i back to activity with recyclerview that use StaggeredGridLayoutManager and shared element.

To show me problem i create small app:
https://github.com/Anton111111/RecyclerViewSharedElement/tree/master/app/src/main/java/anton111111/com/recyclerviewsharedelement

In MainActivity i have RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager. Adapter of this RecyclerView set random height for each item. 

On click item i open DetailsActivity (
https://github.com/Anton111111/RecyclerViewSharedElement/blob/master/app/src/main/java/anton111111/com/recyclerviewsharedelement/DetailsActivity.java )

On DetailsActivity i also have RecyclerView. 
When i open DetailsActivity transition works correctly. But if i scroll RecyclerView and then press back back transition to MainActivity works not correctly.

To show it i create small video: https://youtu.be/zVtS5vVFZ7s

On this video i back from item 14. And how you see it return to item 14 then item 14 after transition animation got to top of recyclerview.

I think my problem in onActivityReenter method, Here is the code:

```
 public void onActivityReenter(int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityReenter(resultCode, data);
  newPosition = data.getIntExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, -1);
  postponeEnterTransition();
  if (newPosition > -1) {
   recyclerView.scrollToPosition(newPosition);
  }
  recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
   new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
     startPostponedEnterTransition();
     return true;
    }
   });
 }
```

On this method i scroll to back item position. And i use  `postponeEnterTransition();` and use `startPostponedEnterTransition();` on `onPreDraw()` of RecyclerView.

Can anyone help me and say how to `startPostponedEnterTransition()` after scroll to position will finish?

Comment: After `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(newPosition);`, instead of `recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver()`, use a `Handler.postDelayed()` to run the `startPostponedEnterTransition();` after some milliseconds delay like 200-300. Handler isn't the solution I know, but it'll help you to identify that timing is the only issue stopping you from achieving you what you want.

Comment: Handler don't help me ;( I tried 3000 delay. But it still finish transition and then item jump to first place on screen. Seem like i need catch while staggered layout finish reorder items

Comment: From the video it looks like the animation is returning to the old position from where it started. I guess after the scrolling, you need to tell animation the new position it needs to end up instead of the old one. I'll try to find how could we do so

Comment: It's happen only if i need do scrolltoposition on back to MainActivity. If i don't need to scroll to show element on screen animation works correctly. I set new position in this https://github.com/Anton111111/RecyclerViewSharedElement/blob/master/app/src/main/java/anton111111/com/recyclerviewsharedelement/MainActivity.java#L68